# Application layout loads as plain text after render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render-to-string

I'm using Gon gem to send some data from Rails to BackBone. 
My `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :init_gon

  def init_gon
    gon.me = render_to_string(template: 'users/_me.json.jbuilder')
  end
end
```

So after this, if I open any page of my web application, it only displays html as plain text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
.....
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is to do with your rendering `gon` data as string. I think you should pass your data without the need to render a string

I don't have any experience of that particular part, but I have used `gon` extensively before. Here's a snippet of a [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast) covering the subject:

> Gon simply creates a script tag then fills a gon variable with the
>   data that we set in the controller. If we want to customize the JSON
>   that’s returned to the client Gon has support for both RABL and
>   Jbuilder templates, both of which have been covered in recent
>   episodes. To customize the data returned by the list of products we
>   can create an index.json.rabl file and define the attributes we want
>   to be returned there:

```
/app/views/products/index.json.rabl
collection Product.limit(10)
attributes :id, :name, :price

/app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    gon.rabl "app/views/products/index.json.rabl", as: "products"
  end
end
```

---

**JBuilder**

Perhaps this will help? There is a way to [render GON data with jBuilder](https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-with-jbuilder) (as I see you are using):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def init_gon
    gon.jbuilder template: 'users/_me.json.jbuilder'
end
```

https://github.com/gazay/gon/wiki/Usage-with-jbuilder

Comment: I just used gon.jbuilder extension as you said, and all works. Thanks very match!